# What are the ways to abiogenically synthetesize Uric acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

The only link I could find was, but I couldn't find it anywhere:

Horbaczewski, Johann (1882). "Synthese der Harnsäure" [Synthesis of uric acid]. Monatshefte für Chemie und verwandte Teile anderer Wissenschaften. 3: 796–797.

This is not a homework question, as I don't have a chemistry background, but I do understand thing about biology. I am trying to work the chain of events in the opposite order: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/Nuc_acid_deg.png

If you look for synthesis of urea, I only find biological sources.